# setup.py build does not exclude tests and add data_files when using cx_Freeze

Tags: python-3.x, cx-freeze, setup.py

I am attempting to create an executable for my python gui app, and need to:

- include a number of image and config files.
- exclude unittest files

I am attempting to include these for  building with setup.py, but I cannot seem to get this to work.  No data files are added, and my test files are incorrectly added to the linb.

My tree structure looks like this:

```
setup.py
mypkg/
    __init__.py
    gui_app.py
icons/
    add.png
    import.png
config/
    mycfg.json
tests
    __init__.py
    tests.py
...
```

I am attempting to use this:

https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#distutils-additional-files

I have the following:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
from codecs import open
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import sys

...

setup(
    ...
    packages=find_packages(exclude=('tests', 'docs')),
    executables=[Executable("./mypkg/gui_app.py", base=base)],
    data_files=[('icons', ["./icons/add.png", "./icons/import.png"]),
                ('config', ["./config/mycfg.json"])],
    ...
)
```

Can anyone suggest how to get this working with python3.6?  Please, no solutions for python2.7 or python3.5 and below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR `cx_Freeze` is a special case that ignores many of the options used by `distutils` and `setuptools` when building wheels or source distributions. Rewrite your `setup()` call to this:

```
setup(
    ...
    executables=[Executable("./mypkg/gui_app.py", base=base)],
    options={
        'build_exe': {
            'packages': find_packages(exclude=('tests', 'docs')),
            'include_files': ['icons', 'config'],
        }
    }
)
```

---

> #### include a number of image and config files

`data_files` is ignored by `cx_Freeze`. Instead, it uses its own argument named `include_files` passed in `options`. According to the docs, it should be a

> list containing files to be copied to the target directory; it is expected that this list will contain strings or 2-tuples for the source and destination; the source can be a file or a directory (in which case the tree is copied except for .svn and CVS directories); the target must not be an absolute path

So what you specified in `data_files` turns into

```
setup(
    ...
    options={'build_exe': {'include_files': ['icons', 'config']}},
)
```

This will copy the files without changing their relative paths. To change them, pass the target paths in tuples. For example, to write files in `icons` to target dir `ico`:

```
options={'build_exe': {'include_files': [('icons', 'ico'), 'config']}}
```

To write `config/mycfg.json` as `config/othercfg.json`:

```
options={'build_exe': {'include_files': [('config/mycfg.json', 'config/othercfg.json')]}}
```

> #### exclude unittest files

Same goes for `packages` - when passed to `setup()` function, this option does not do anything with `cx_Freeze`. Use the `packages` argument to `options` instead:

> comma separated list of packages to include, which includes all submodules in the package

Beware that submodules are included silently - be cautious what you pass in the list, especially when you use `find_packages()`. For example,

```
find_packages(exclude=['tests.*'])
```

will exclude all subpackages of `tests`, but not `tests` itself. So when declaring

```
'packages': find_packages(exclude=['tests.*'])
```

all the subpackages excluded in `find_packages` will be included back because of including the root package `tests`. So the exclusion has no effect.

[Source](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/distutils.html#build-exe).

Comment: Hero post, and thank you for guiding me to the documentation.  I had managed to get some fo this working since the post using `package_data`, but was struggling with wanting to not nest data files inside my package dir.  Will test this out asap...  Quick follow-up question...  Using 3.6, do I have an alternative to `cx_Freeze`, is this preferred/only build approach, and if so, would your answer be more opinion or fact?

Comment: [There are several alternatives to `cx_Freeze`](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/shipping/freezing/), however only `cx_Freeze` and `pyinstaller` being able to freeze for multiple target platforms.

Comment: Thanks.  I managed to get this working, but sadly this broke the file paths, as the packages are placed under `lib/`, so the relative path to `icons/` from the module is broken.  A good exercise nonetheless.  Lastly...  I see that your solution still suggests to `find_packages` from `setuptools`.  The `cx_Freeze` link you shared shows that this can use `"excludes": ["docs", "tests"]` instead.  Perhaps for the sake of consistency, this is preferred?

Comment: To answer my own last comment on paths: http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#using-data-files

Comment: I don't see why you can't use `find_packages`, just keep in mind the behaviour of `cx_Freeze`'s `packages` arg with including submodules.